# Getting the row number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to get my user's ranking (row number) respecting to other users' points. In my ancient codes (from 3 years ago), there was no error, but now I tried same codes and MySQL is giving so much error.

My old code;

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, ID,nick,balance
FROM users , (SELECT @rank := 0) r
ORDER BY balance DESC
) k
WHERE k.nick = '$nickname'");
```

I need to get a rank like this;

```
SELECT *rank* FROM users WHERE users who have more than 10 balance AND users have less than 100 balance
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with my code and how I can fix that? Thank you.

Example:

```
User 0 Balance 7
User 1 Balance 15
User 2 Balance 55
User 3 Balance 104
```

Expected ranking of user 2 is 2. (More than 10, less than 100.)

Comment: Use `Where` clause  `..Where balance > 10 and balance < 100`

Comment: So VR46 has got it - a WHERE clause in the subquery

Comment: @Strawberry Sadly, it's not working.

Comment: Your error message refers to a different query. Maybe take a break?

Comment: @Strawberry yeah, break is soon. :) But here is the weird thing; http://i.hizliresim.com/z5v2Q6.jpg :/

Comment: Your phpmyadmin appears to be broken. I would encourage you to use the CLI; for many operations it's simpler, quicker, and more robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET( balance, (    
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( balance
ORDER BY balance DESC ) 
FROM uye WHERE balance>50 AND balance<1000 )
) AS rank
FROM UYE
WHERE ID =  '49'
```

Here is the answer I managed to run.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use:

> SELECT  ID,nick,balance, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @rank AS) rank FROM users